Recovering a commit that has been lost after pull request
I merged my branch revamp/studio-creator inside main via a PR.
It merged fine, however I realized that main branch didn't have the most up to date code, there were parts that I would want from studio-creator branch but those were not merged over to main.
I didn't give it much thought and just deleted my local instance and cloned the repo again (This might be disastrous but I thought since my changes are already pushed, there's no risk). I cloned the repo and I still saw the commit made yesterday (12th June is missing).
GitHub commit history of all branches is only showing latest commit as one done on 29th May. Since main branch was old anyway I renamed it to main2 and renamed by studio-creator branch as main. Then I deleted main2. However now I am left with a scenario where the latest commit is nowhere to be found.
It's not in the commit list (which is weird since the PR was merged yesterday and the commit history is reflecting work of past 2 weeks, don't know why is that!).
Can someone please help me with this scenario? The commit we lost had work of past 2 weeks and it is absolutely important to get this work back.
Already logged a complaint to GitHub support but their response times are very bad so that's why posting here, hoping someone would be able to help!



If the branch was in the local repo that you removed and you had not pushed that branch, you are out of luck in terms of getting git to help you... it's up to the FS then (trash, getting stuff from back in time if possible by the FS, etc).

@eftshift0 No, the changes were pushed to Github. That's what the PR I am referring to was created, to merge those changes into main.

Was it some sort of squash-merge?

@RomainValeri Nope, just a standard merge. It's mind boggling what happened there.

@Ashar Inspect the merge commit with git cat-file -p <hash> and look for the parents. Inspect them. One of them should be your lost commit.

@RomainValeri I wasn't sure about the  so I used the one from PR. The problem is it's only showing the commit from 2 weeks ago. There is also supposed to be a commit I did 11 hours ago (just before creating and merging this PR). Also I added both the screenshots of the PR and what git cat-file -p  output.

As we can see in the output you added, your "merge commit" is not one. Only one parent, regular commit. Could it be that something in the UI mislead you into silently doing a squash-merge? (and its timestamp indeed indicates it's a days-old one)

Let us continue this discussion in chat.

Unfortunately, your second sentence has a logical flaw in it: "It merged fine, however I realized that main branch didn't have the most up to date code...". What actually happened was that the remote copy of revamp/studio-creator didn't have the most up to date code. Presumably because you didn't push your latest version of it so the PR didn't include it.  At that moment it's possible the only place the up-to-date code existed was in your local repo, which, it seems you deleted. If you're lucky, maybe you pushed the branch to a different (but similar) remote branch name?

Thanks @TTT Yes you're right. I think what happened here is I did the commit through git commit -m "Bla Bla Bla" but forgot to do git push. Bonkers :(

GitHub stores the PR head as a ref. If the remote  name is origin, you can use
git ls-remote origin

to list all remote refs. Pull request head refs are under refs/pull/<id>/head. For example:
123b75fc4921239e4b2123cffdc921232a8344dd        refs/pull/16/head

While a push to a branch of a pull request updates the PR head ref, after the MR is closed, I would not expect it to.
You can fetch the remove commit with
git fetch origin refs/pull/16/head

and then refer to it with FETCH_HEAD or the commit id directly.

If you know the sha1 commit ID of the commit you are now missing, you may also be able to fetch it directly from the remote, if it still knows of it.
git fetch origin 123b75fc4921239e4b2123cffdc921232a8344dd

Then you can refer to it locally and create a branch on it, inspect it, work with it.

dea78decc73e9396bf9a13af9194e6bb1931871b refs/heads/main
dea78decc73e9396bf9a13af9194e6bb1931871b refs/heads/revamp/studio-creator
ccdd9bdbd657596c4d2a85441dd891511b87ed86 refs/heads/revert-1-revamp/studio-creator
dea78decc73e9396bf9a13af9194e6bb1931871b refs/pull/1/head
ccdd9bdbd657596c4d2a85441dd891511b87ed86 refs/pull/2/head```

Thanks @Kissaki, I tried git ls-remote origin and it generated this output. So here I'm effectively only seeing two commits, one with dea... which is the one done on 29th and the second ccdd9... Latter is the one I just created in the hope of reverting back the changes. PR containing this commit was never merged.
